# Part name of this IC - Analog Devices, 8-pin, "A 0D"

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

[image]

I want to know the part name of this IC.

Comment: It's an Analog Devices part, looks like an MSOP-8 package. Beyond that, you may just have to look through their catalog until you find a matching part.

Comment: In the Analog Device part search site, you can search by Top Marking.

Comment: @김상윤, please put the part number in your question title instead of only "Part name is this IC". It will attract someone who knows the answer. It will help in search engine results for others in future.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is the AD8655 op amp.

The symbol on the left side is the logo for Analog Devices and in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8655_8656.pdf) for the AD8655, the branding is listed as "A0D", matching your photo. I was able to find this using the Google search query: "A0D" site:analog.com

Comment: Thanks your help!